# Auto Deployment for .NET websites

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I'm looking for an easy to use, intuitive tool to automatically pull data from my source control and deploy the code to several environments (a dev server, test server, may be staging, and live server)

I've already looked at TeamCity (it's a great tool, but not intuitive what so ever and it tries to do far tooooo much)

I don't like Cruise Control either;

I'm just wondering if there's a .NET specific tool for packaging and deploying code straight out of a source control?

cheers

Comment: id say you need to go back and persist with teamcity. It is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If a build server is "too much" for you, my advice is to combine some "low level" tool:

- WebDeploy for packaging and deploy (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx)
- MsBuild or PSake to script the operations (fetch from source control, build, packaging with webdeploy and deploy with webdeploy)

if you need to also run tests or schedule your script, then a build server like TeamCity / Jenkins / BuildMaster is definitely the way to go. Personality I like Jenkins, wich is free, mature and really well supported by the community.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer for Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview), I know we have a lot of users that use our tool exactly for this. We've worked hard to design it to be as easy to use as possible, and have some wizard/templates to help you get set-up with .NET application build/deployments.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged "MsBuild", i do believe you know MsBuild could achieve it.

I answered a similar question in programmers SO, you might want to check it out - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206877/handling-deployment-to-multiple-environments/206887#206887

about pull data (check out code) from your source control, as long as your source control software (such as svn) does support command line, it would have no issue